# Should JavaScript npm packages be minified?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I have created [quite a few npm packages](https://www.npmjs.com/~mrmartineau), but I still don't know the right answer to this question: "Should JavaScript npm packages be minified?"

I have always understood that minifying minified code is a bad idea so have not done that in my npm packages. However, I see that some npm packages [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios), [styled-components](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components) provide minified versions of their "dist" files alongside unminified versions, while [Lodash](https://lodash.com) does not.

Which are right? Who would consume the minified versions?

Comment: I think this comes down to a matter of opinion, since there is no "correct" answer (and voted to close for that reason) — but if I were releasing packages I would make both available ... minified for improved performance and un-minified for debuggability.

Comment: Minifying Javascript is usually for the benefit of web browsers on slow connections. Since node.js usually runs on the server, and the file is saved on the server, you're not downloading the script when you execute it.

Comment: @Barmar Perhaps I should make it more explicit that in most cases (I may be wrong in generalising this) developers will be bundling and minifying all their code anyway, so is there really a need to minify at the package level?

Comment: if you minify, then it's very easy to use the package from browser through cdn, such as `<script src="https://unpkg.com/underscore@1.8.3/underscore-min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>`

Comment: This question should be re-opened. As the highest-voted answer shows, a great many objective and useful points can be made that help people make better decisions about whether or not to minify. Closing such a question as "opinion-based" makes no sense.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

**It all depends on the environment of your package consumers**

---

### NodeJS

For a NodeJS audience your package does not have to be minified, since node runtimes normally have *direct file access* to the `node_modules` folder. No network transfers are required, and no additional code transformations are performed prior to running the code.

---

### Bundlers / build pipelines

For consumption through a dev environment that uses a bundler in its build pipeline your package **is best not** minified. In most cases package consumers do implement their own minification process as part of their builds. Moreover, when providing your package in a module format for example:

- the dependency tree of implementing codebases can be analyzed more accurately, which might lead to better tree-shaking performance.
- Common dependencies across packages are actually **the same symbols** for all such packages (modules are 'singletons'). This helps with code splitting as well as with keeping bundles small.

*The above statement relies on the assumption that, if multiple source files are included, minification is preceded by a bundling process. Minifying separate modules is uncommon. If you do provide separate modules, e.g. for a RequireJS runtime in the browser, minification is still relevant, since these files are mostly fetched over the network.*

---

If you decide not to supply minified code, it's still advisable to run your own tests to see if a standard minification process - e.g. with UglifyJS - does not break the software.

Despite that it is for many consumers unnecessary to minify your code, it's still advisable to supply a minified bundle *in addition to* your regular distribution, just in case somebody could benefit from it.

> For plugins / extensions for frameworks like Angular, Vue, Ember etc. it's usually unnecessary to minify your code, since they all implement their own build pipeline, often through a *cli*.

---

### Script tags / CDN

These are the cases towards which minification is primarily targeted. If you're hosting a file on a CDN, or otherwise provide it over the web for direct `<script>` tag usage, what you see is what you get. In both cases the file will have to go over the network. Minification saves bytes.

---

### Minification v.s. transpilation

A very important distinction is to be made between these two. Although minification is not always necessary, it **is** usually your responsibility to transpile any code that is unlikely to be 100% compatible with the target environments of your package audience. This includes:

- Transpiling new `ES20XX` syntax to - probably - ES5
- Polyfilling any `ES20XX` API implementations

---

### Minification and bundling

If your package consists of a **single bundle** instead of a bunch of separate modules, minification is always a safe bet. Since a bundler will never try anything funny with a single module/entity (like tree-shaking), it's likely your code will technically not change at all by any build process.

---

### Debugging

If you're going to distribute a minified bundle of your software, it would be nice to also ship a non-minified version for debugging purposes.

Comment: Does it relate to the JS files we have to specify in the `package.json` of the library? Which file would you choose for the `main` and `module` field, respectively? E.g., if I use Webpack as a bundler of my library: `"main": "dist/non-minified-umd-version-of-library.js"` (non-minified UMD version of the library, having the `dist/` directory in `.gitignore`, users will have to run `npm run build` to generate `dist/non-minified-umd-version-of-library.js`) and `"module": "src/es6-modules-version-of-library.js"` (direct ES6 source entry point)? Correct?