# Webpack bundling emits "require" statements in the distribution file

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, webpack, es6-modules

I have a TypeScript project, and I use Webpack to bundle the code to single JavaScript file. I'm using **ESM** only. When I try to run the distribution file by running: `node ./dist/index.js` I get this error:

```
const external_minimist_namespaceObject = require("minimist");
                                          ^

ReferenceError: require is not defined in ES module scope, you can use import instead
This file is being treated as an ES module because it has a '.js' file extension and 'package.json' contains "type": "module". To treat it as a CommonJS script, rename it to use the '.cjs' file extension.
```

Indeed, I configured `"type": "module"` in the `package.json` file.
I have this script to run the Webpack: `"dist": "node --loader ts-node/esm node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js -c ./webpack.config.ts",` in my `package.json` file.

This is my `webpack.config.ts` file:

```
import path from 'node:path';
import fs from 'node:fs/promises';
import { fileURLToPath } from 'node:url';

import webpack from 'webpack';
import nodeExternals from 'webpack-node-externals';
import TsconfigPathsPlugin from 'tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin';
import WebpackShellPluginNext from 'webpack-shell-plugin-next';

const packageJsonData = await fs.readFile('package.json', 'utf-8');
const packageJsonObject = JSON.parse(packageJsonData);
const version = packageJsonObject.version;

const __dirname = path.dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url));

const configuration: webpack.Configuration = {
    context: __dirname,
    mode: 'production',
    target: 'node',
    entry: './src/index.ts',
    // * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48673408/should-javascript-npm-packages-be-minified
    optimization: { minimize: false },
    externals: [nodeExternals({ modulesDir: path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules') })],
    experiments: { outputModule: true },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'ts-loader',
                        options: { configFile: 'tsconfig.build.json' },
                    },
                ],
                exclude: /node_modules/,
            },
        ],
    },
    plugins: [
        new WebpackShellPluginNext({
            onBuildStart: {
                scripts: ['rimraf dist'],
                blocking: true,
            },
            safe: true,
        }),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            __PACKAGE_VERSION__: JSON.stringify(version),
        }),
    ],
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts'],
        plugins: [
            new TsconfigPathsPlugin({
                configFile: './tsconfig.base.json',
                extensions: ['.ts'],
            }),
        ],
    },
    output: {
        filename: 'index.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        library: { type: 'module' },
        chunkFormat: 'module',
    },
};

export default configuration;
```

And this is my `tsconfig.base.json` file which is the important one:

```json
{
    "extends": "./tsconfig.paths.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES2018",
        "module": "ESNext",
        "moduleResolution": "bundler",
        "noEmit": true,
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "allowJs": false,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "strict": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "isolatedModules": true,
        "incremental": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "allowUnreachableCode": false,
        "allowUnusedLabels": false,
        "alwaysStrict": true,
        "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "noImplicitOverride": true,
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "noImplicitThis": true,
        "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": true,
        "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true,
        "noUnusedLocals": true,
        "noUnusedParameters": true,
        "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types", "./@types"]
    }
}
```

Webpack completes successfully, but I cannot run the distribution file with NodeJS (`node ./dist/index.js`). Why does the distribution file contain `require` statements instead of `import` to successfully run with `ESM`?

Comment: I created a simple content for `src/index.ts` to reproduce it, like, `import path from 'path'; import minim from 'minimist'; console.log(path, minim);`. I notice that for the output it has this for "path": `__WEBPACK_EXTERNAL_createRequire(import.meta.url)("path")`, but somehow didn't do the same automatically for "minimist". (I have no idea how this happens, but hopefully this comment can help others figure out the reason)

Comment: I managed to find a reason in `node_modules/webpack/lib/ExternalModule.js`. In the `_getSourceData` method, when the `request = "minimist"`, it detects the external type as `externalType = "commonjs"`. Then it uses `getSourceForCommonJsExternal(request)` which in turn outputs the require. Node's path is treated differently because `externalType = "node-commonjs"` in this case.

Comment: We could technically manually delete line 556: `return getSourceForCommonJsExternal(request);` so that it falls-through to the "node-commonjs". The replaced version also makes sense (when `this.buildInfo.module` is true, it should use `getSourceForCommonJsExternalInNodeModule`), but then modifying a script in `node_modules` means that it will go wrong when you re-install it (and it can easily go wrong when someone else tries to reproduce your project). I hope someone else has a better idea.

Comment: @qrsngky there is on going thread regarding this issue here: https://github.com/webpack/webpack-cli/issues/3728

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to do as follows:

```
    externals: [
        nodeExternals({
            modulesDir: path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules'),
            importType: (moduleName) => `import ${moduleName}`,
        }),
    ],
```

This will inject `import` statements instead of `requires`